# Why is icon for folder with name test different?

Tags: visual-studio-code

[image]

I created two folders, but the colors of the two folders are different.
What does this mean?

Answer (score 0):

VSCode interprets the folder named `test` to contain tests for your code.

Hence the icon with a test tube.

Answer (score 0):

It's the test folder icon in the [material icon theme](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/PKief/vscode-material-icon-theme/main/images/folderIcons.png)